# contenteditable для уже имеющихся элементов

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Ниже код плагина для вставки цитаты (текст и автор).

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('quote', {
init: function (editor) {
    editor.addCommand('add_quote',
        new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('quoteDialog'));

    editor.ui.addButton('quote', {
        label: 'Insert quote',
        command: 'add_quote',
        toolbar: 'insert'
    });
}
});

CKEDITOR.dialog.add('quoteDialog', function (editor) {
return {
    title: 'Embed Quote',
    width: 405,
    height: 271,
    resize: false,
    contents: [
        {
            id: 'tab-quote',
            label: 'Embed Quote',
            elements: [
                {
                    type: 'textarea',
                    id: 'quote-content',
                    label: 'Content',
                    validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty("Content field cannot be empty.")
                },
                {
                    type: 'text',
                    id: 'quote-author',
                    label: 'Author'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    onShow: function () {
        var dialog = this;
        dialog.setValueOf('tab-quote', 'quote-content', editor.getSelection().getSelectedText());
    },
    onOk: function () {
        var dialog = this,
            quoteWrap = editor.document.createElement("blockquote"),
            quote = editor.document.createElement("p").addClass('quote'),
            author = editor.document.createElement("p").addClass('author');
        author.setText(dialog.getValueOf('tab-quote', 'quote-author'));
        quote.setText(dialog.getValueOf('tab-quote', 'quote-content'));
        quote.appendTo(quoteWrap);
        author.appendTo(quoteWrap);
        editor.insertElement(quoteWrap);
    }
}
});
```

При этом на все блоки цитаты нужно повесть contenteditable = 'false', их редактирование возможно только через такое же диалоговое окно. 
Если при создании новой цитаты всё довольно просто (в конце прописываем `quoteWrap.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false')`, то как быть с уже имеющимися цитатами на странице? Как их подцепить для дальнейшей работы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для обработки уже имеющихся элементов можно использовать событие `instanceReady`, позволяющее работать с редактором после его инициализации.

Ниже упрощенный код того, что необходимо было реализовать:

```js
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function (ev) {
    var elements = ev.editor.editable().find("blockquote"),
        count = elements.count();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        elements.getItem(i).setAttribute("contenteditable", "false")
  .on("click", function () {
            ev.editor.openDialog("quoteDialog");
        });
    }
});
```